# How is this public key == private key

Tags: php, wordpress, key, licensing, license-key

This is a part of a test with this [wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/software-license-manager/) which is basically a license manager. I am trying to understand the internals of the system. Here is how it works.

Once the plugin is activated, it generates a private key `55d0ec3f9db414.02268045` using a simple function `'lic_verification_private_secret' => uniqid('', true)`. Now, when someone makes a purchase of an item eg. **a wordpress plugin**, a public license key `55d5d22ab70d2` is generated (using `uniqid()`).  The public key is then sent to the customer's email id. The customer inputs that key into his site and sends a request to the license server. Below is a function about how the license manager plugin @server matches the private key with public key.

```
static function verify_secret_key() {
     $slm_options = get_option('slm_plugin_options');
     $private_secret_key = $slm_options['lic_verification_private_secret'];
     $public_key = strip_tags($_REQUEST['secret_key']); //this is sent in the query string
     if ($public_key == $private_secret_key) {
     // send a message back to client saying the key is verified.
}
```

All this works, so basically where I am stumped is how the below equation is valid ? What part of the picture am I missing ?

```
55d5d22ab70d2 == 55d0ec3f9db414.02268045
```

---

Update - I have performed this test and it echoes false which i guess is obvious.

```
echo '55d0ec3f9db414.02268045' === '55d5d22ab70d2' ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: @MarkBaker there are only differences between lose vs strict comparison if you're comparing the two variables that are not of the same type.

Comment: I'm guessing the public and private keys are used as key to sign messages, they're not intended to be compared. A public/private key authentication system works in such a way that a public key encrypts a message and only the private key and unencrypt the message. So anyone can send you a message, but only you can read them (and thus prove your identity).

Comment: @Halcyon I am trying to grasp what you said but there is no message encryption or any other type of encryption happening in the plugin.

Comment: Since you're dealing with licenses I don't think you need public and private keys. A secret shared key is sufficient.

Comment: I think you are right. Could you please elaborate your concept as an answer and possibly provide a pseudo-code example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared secret key:

```
function generate_signature($message, $secret) {
     $serialized_message = serialize($message);
     return md5($serialized_message . $secret);
}

$secret = "i like pie";
$content = array(
    "i like" => "pie",
    "pancakes" => "are also nice"
);
$message = serialize(array(
    "signature" => generate_signature($content , $secret),
    "content" => $content
));

// send the message

$message = unserialize($_POST["message"]);
$signature = generate_signature($message["content"], $secret);
if ($signature === $message["signature"]) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "you don't like pie?";
}
```

The secret key can be the license btw, since that's what you want to keep secret.

Comment: I would recommend using hash_equals() instead of === for added security,